# Theoretically, if we send a square wave, of frequency equal to the pole frequency, through an RC lowpass filter is the output shifted by -45 degrees?

Tags: filter, frequency-response

The square wave power is concentrated at the pole frequency with harmonics at integer multiples of this, so this main component would be phase shifted by -45 degrees and attenuated at .707*Vin and the lesser harmonics would be phased shifted by differing amounts but these higher frequency components would be attenuated more heavily from the output signal. Would the output approximately be another square wave phased shifted by -45 degrees?

Comment: The square wave is every ***odd*** integer multiple, starting at 1. Not ***all*** integer multiples. An RC lowpass set with its \$-3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ at the \$\times 1\$ frequency of the square wave will be \$-45^\circ\$. But at \$\times 3\$ it will be \$-10\:\text{dB}\$ and \$\approx -71.6^\circ\$. At \$\times 5\$ it will be \$-14.15\:\text{dB}\$ and \$\approx -78.7^\circ\$. Because the RC is set (I gather) at the primary square wave frequency, you'd expect to see a mostly RC-decay curve during each half-cycle. Peak to peak would be about 90%, at a guess.

Comment: @periblepsis That really should be an answer - go on, make it an answer so I can give you ten points.

Comment: @SimonFitch Then I'd have to write out the Heaviside function, do Laplace of the square wave to get the funky tanh thing, then apply the RC to that in s-space, and inverse-Laplace all that crap back to the time domain -- only to show that it closely mimics an RC decay, kind of. I'm feeling way too lazy today. Can't I just say he's wrong?

Comment: @periblepsis Understood, I get it. What you said was sufficient, though, at least I thought so.

Comment: @SimonFitch Oh, heck with it. I figured out how to avoid the Heaviside function and inverse Laplace disaster.

Comment: @SimonFitch I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782935/laplace-transform-of-a-square-wave-function) just now on using the Heaviside function for a square wave. ***That's*** why I wanted to avoid it here. At least I remembered the tanh() and why i wanted to avoid the whole thing here! I like math. Well, knowing how to use it, anyway. But... sometimes it is just mindless drudgery and almost no beauty. This is one such to me, anyway. Just an anvil and hammer in this case. Mindless and almost painful.

Comment: @periblepsis props to you, I was unaware of the tanh result. For me I was satisfied that if different harmonics are phase shifted by different amounts, there cannot possibly be a square wave out. That's about as far as my thinking went on this one.

Comment: @SimonFitch I have a stupid love of mathematical beauty (when and where I find it.) I don't always care about practical use. Some things are just amazing in how my mind sees the equations in motion and action. It can be beautiful and entrancing. I'm one who may pursue Coxeter's polytopes for days at a stretch, for example. But this is just pure drudgery. There's nothing beautiful about "HI" for a time, then "LO" for a time. Repeat and rinse. It's just brutal math. Nothing of value to be seen. Hate it after a fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***Wrong***: *"with harmonics at integer multiples"*. The square wave is every ***odd*** integer multiple, starting at 1. Not at ***all*** integer multiples.
- ***Right***: *"main component would be phase shifted by -45 degrees"*. An RC lowpass set with its \$-3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ at the \$\times 1\$ frequency of the square wave will be \$-45^\circ\$.
- ***Roughly right***: *"lesser harmonics would be phased shifted by differing amounts but these higher frequency components would be attenuated more heavily from the output signal"*. At \$\times 3\$ it will be \$-10\:\text{dB}\$ and \$\approx -71.6^\circ\$. At \$\times 5\$ it will be \$-14.15\:\text{dB}\$ and \$\approx -78.7^\circ\$.
- ***Wrong***: *"the output approximately be another square wave phased shifted by -45 degrees"*. With the RC is set for \$-3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ at the primary square wave frequency, you'd expect to see a mostly RC-decay curve during each half-cycle. (Peak to peak would be about 90%, at a guess.)

Suppose the square wave is \$1\:\text{kHz}\$ and that you are using \$R=1.59154943\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$C=100\:\text{nF}\$. The RC time constant is \$\tau=159.154943\:\mu\text{s}\$ and the period between half-cycles of the square wave is \$500\:\mu\text{s}\$, or \$\pi\times\tau\$ put another way.

Here's a nice table that google threw at me:

[image]

At \$3\times\tau\$ you'd expect about 95% of the signal. \$\pi\gt 3\$, so better than that in this case.

In short, this should look "mostly" like an RC decay curve, going up 95% and down 95%, or at least 90% peak to peak, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the result. The amplitude is 92% peak-to-peak, so periblepsis wasn't far off.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. \$\pi\gt 3\$ so it should be a little more than 90%. `(1-exp(-pi))^2` is 91.5439606%. So that would be my prediction if I wanted to get precise about it.